# chromedriver cannot load GWT Plugin for selenium tests

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to load the GWT Plugin for the chrome driver the solution from [Selenium Chromedriver causes Chrome to start without configured plugins, bookmarks and other settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425799/selenium-chromedriver-causes-chrome-to-start-without-configured-plugins-bookmar) doesn't seem to work. As Directory I tried:

```
 capability.setCapability("chrome.switches", ["--load-extension="+Constants.PATH_TO_GWT_PLUGIN);
```

Constants.PATH_TO_GWT_PLUGIN values:

```
<>\User Data\Default\Extensions\jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim\1.0.11357_0
<>\User Data\Default\Extensions\jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim\
```

I also tried the plugin switch:

```
 capability.setCapability("chrome.switches", ["--load-plugin="+Constants.PATH_TO_GWT_PLUGIN);
```

with PATH_TO_GWT_PLUGIN:

```
<>\User Data\Default\Extensions\jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim\<PATH TO DLL>
```

But none of the above worked. What do I miss?