# Selenium Python: avoid incognito mode

Tags: python, selenium

Having this code on a Mac:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.test.com/")
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('asdf')
button.click().send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

When I run it, it opens an incognito mode Chrome window, but I don't wanna do that, indeed I want to open an ordinary Chrome session.

How?

Comment: Does Chrome start in Incognito mode when you run it normally?

Comment: Nope, it starts with an ordinary session.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754760/how-to-make-selenium-webdriver-open-in-google-chrome-without-incognito